# Good broad review of agent-based modeling?

Tags: graph-theory, textbook-recommendation, random-graphs, mathematical-modeling

Trying to find some good review of agent-based models and networks, specifically models that are defined by a graph of interacting nodes, that covers analysis of collective behavior based on model of individual behavior and a model if interaction. Keywords would be: opinion dynamics, correlated behavior, phase transitions in complex networks. Are there any surveys or books that cover modern advances in this area?

Answer (score 4):

This is just out (April 2015): [An Introduction to Agent-Based Modeling](https://mitpress.mit.edu/books/introduction-agent-based-modeling)

> Agent-based modeling attempts to understand natural and social
>   phenomena by recreating them in computer
>   simulations,
>   showing how high-level, macroscopic properties, such as crystal
>   formation, tumor shape, flocking, population cycles, social
>   coordination, and transportation networks, can spontaneously emerge
>   from lower-level interactions among agents rather than being
>   explicitly programmed into a model.

[Table of Contents](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sites/default/files/Wilensky_revised_pp_TOC.pdf)